Amperage needed for new appliances
I purchased this fixer upper and I am still discovering things about it. The main in the breaker box is 200A and there are plenty of slots available in the box. I am a tad surprised as to low amperage that goes to individual floors. For instance the whole second floor is on breaker 1, which is 15A and so is the kitchen with 15A. See photo of the breaker box.
The previous owner had a sub-panel (see picture 2, with slow and fast fuses) that was used I think only for a dishwashing machine (I threw it out). The white cable was going from the sub-panel in the basement to the kitchen (first floor). Why did they run a sub-panel, could not they have cable going directly from the main breaker box? I do not know whether dishwashing machines are 240V.
My question is whether I can ran lines from the main breaker that would feed a point of use water tank (10 gal) on the second floor (120V likely), also an electrical range in the kitchen (1st floor) which is 240V.
My fancy would have it that I would have an outlet on the hind side of the house that would cater for my welding 120/240V...
In other words, why would one want to run sub-panels for this, rather than have lines run directly from the main box, since there are plenty of slots available?
 

Some people like to run one big cable to a sub panel close to where the power will be used.  Depending on your location, recent code requires two 20 amp circuit for kitchens and at least one 20 amp per bathroom, with GFCI protection.

–
Ecnerwal
Yes, sub-panel, thank you. Code violations for sure. That cable was not even properly fixed on the rafters.

@crip659
I have installed GFCI in both, but amperage I have not changed, it is still 15A each.  Kitchen power use point is about 40-50ft from the breaker box. The subpanel I found is about 10ft from the breaker box. The building is I think 1948 in Eastern Ohio.

You need larger wire size if you use larger breakers.  That fuse box might have been from before the panel was installed.  48 would have had maybe 60 amp service unless a big house and have maybe 100 amp.  That panel probably post 70s/80s.  15 amps can run kitchen counter top appliances, but only one at a time.  Can make coffee and then toast, or have a tripped breaker.

First, the bad news - that's a 100 amp panel, not a 200A panel. 2 breakers at 100A is...100A. At 240V, but not 200A, period.
The 20 spaces seem like a lot because you're presumably in a house where someone upgraded the old 30 or 60A fuse panel to 100A and didn't add much in the way of new circuits when doing so. That also pretty much explains your question about sub-panels - they were what was there with the old fuse panel, presumably, and were left, presumably. They thought 100A was huge, and you (currently) think 20 spaces is huge. It's not. It might be big enough, depending. It might not. You should do a load calculation per the NEC article 220 procedure for those. You may require a service upgrade to support all the loads you want to run.
Under current code (which depending on the age of the various parts, you may not have to meet, but if you'd like to make coffee and toast at the same time, you'll want to) you need at least:

(minimum - more is OK) 2 20A circuits (GFCI protected) feeding the kitchen countertop outlets (and pretty much nothing else, but can extend into dining area.)
Most kitchen appliances that are not "countertop" appliances require another circuit, or several circuits depending on the load.
A 2-pole (2-space) 40 or 50A breaker for your electric range.
1 20A circuit (GFCI protected) for up to 2 bathrooms, but 1 per bathroom is better if you can manage it, not shared with anything but another bathroom.
a number of 15 or 20A circuits for general outlets and lighting depending on the square footage of the house. Mostly AFCI protected. Unfinished basement and garage, if any, GFCI protected.
Laundry area requires a 20A GFCI circuit for the washing machine; depending on the dryer it might use the same circuit or it might require a 30A 240V circuit (again, two spaces for two poles.)
At least one GFCI protected and weather resistant outdoor outlet at the front, and at least one at the back of the building.
A dedicated circuit for your heating appliance (boiler, furnace heat pump, etc.) (you have a 15A 120V for this now)
A dedicated circuit for your cooling appliance, if any (unless you have a single heat pump doing both heating and cooling) (you have a 20A 240V for this now)
You mention wanting to add a point of use water heater - that will need a dedicated circuit, even if it's 120V.

Where upgrading from 15A to 20A you will most likely need to replace existing 14 AWG wires/cables with 12 AWG wires/cables.

Can you provide a citation for a gas water heater's ignition needing a dedicated circuit? (Agreed that electric and most heatpump water heaters require dedicated circuits, though)

@ThreePhaseEel Adding a "120V 10 gallon point of use" water heater was mentioned in the question.  I doubt that's  to be gas fired as described.

Ah.  I see, missed that, thanks

@Ecnerwal I must be missing the thing about the connected 2x100A main. If it is only 100A, why did they bother with two, rather than put just one 100A?  In changing the receptacles and switches I noticed that the copper wires used seem to be 12, and perhaps even thicker, but I have not measured it. At those places some of the copper wire endings seems to be brittle. Until now, I did not know copper can be brittle. This may be partially due to people mindlessly breaking the wire so much so that in some receptacles there was hardly any wire left. All wiring has metal sheeting except the subpanel

That's very basic "how the USA/Canada power system works" information that you really should review in a nice clear book from the library before you get into trouble doing electrical work. Our power is 240V (or 208 in some 3-phase supplied areas) delivered as 2 separate hot wires (thus, the two 100A breakers conjoined) 120v from the ground and neutral.  240V loads get 2 hots, 120V loads get one hot and a neutral, 240/120V loads get two hots and a neutral, and in anything built properly in the last 50 years or more everything gets ground.

The cables with "metal sheeting" are some type of armored cable. Is the insulation on the wires in them plastic or cloth? Cloth is typically older and has a nasty habit of falling apart when moved after 70-100 years, so be very, very careful if you have that.
